# Debugger has detached: object registy had 1 entry. Android Logcat Message

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

My Android apps are running ,but can't view anything on logcat view. When I start eclipse,I get this message

```
Debugger has detached: object registy had 1 entry.
```

What does this message mean? It wasn't happening before,until yesterday where I wrote a new app. I don't think that my code is wrong,but the debugger has detached for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take off all breakpoints that you put in your code. 
In Eclipse:
Window->Show View->(Other->Debug->)Breakpoints. Hope this helps you.

UPDATE:

In Android Studio (see marks on attached screenshot) you can choose which breakpoints would you like to remove by hitting upper button or just disable all existing breakpoints by hitting lower button.

[image: Open debugger pane]

Comment: Yeap. Fixed it.Thank you very much sir!

Comment: what if i use android studio?

Comment: how to fix in android studio?

Answer (score 4):

When [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) attaches, it uses the same connection as a debugger.  When it disconnects, you get that message.  Had an actual debugger been attached, the object registry would have more than one entry in it.

Try this: with the DDMS view active in Eclipse, disconnect USB, then reconnect it.  If you scroll back in logcat you should see that, when the USB connection dropped, a "debugger has detached" message was emitted by every debuggable app that was running.

Apps are only debuggable if they have the `android:debuggable` flag set in their manifest, or you're on a developer ("userdebug") device (which has the system property `ro.debuggable` set to 1).  If you're on a production device, you'll generally only see the "detached" message for apps you're developing that happen to be running.

You can safely ignore the message.